# Modifying Stored Procedure using Servername and Database Name

Tags: sql-server

I've already searched online if it works but unfortunately, I did not found any answers. I just want to ask if this is possible or not, because when I try the code below it says:

> Database 'IPAddress' does not exist. Make sure that the name is
>   entered correctly.

I know the credentials of the said ip address and I can easily log in and run this sp. I already add the server to link server its just a matter of curiosity if this is possible.

```sql
USE [IPAddress].[DatabaseName]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Name]    Script Date: 1/14/2020 10:36:26 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name]
```

Comment: `USE` only takes a database name. To use a different server you actually have to log on to it. You can do ugly things with linked servers but this is not recommended.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it before but apparently you can use `EXEC AT`

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/

Something like this

```
EXEC ('USE [Database] GO ALTER PROC spName.....') AT [LinkedServer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use USE command that way. You can only put database name for USE command. [Read more about USE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Instead, you can achieve the same using SQLCMD mode in SSMS. [Read more on SQLCMD mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2311/using-the-ssms-query-editor-in-sqlcmd-mode/)

```sql
:CONNECT [ipaddress]
USE [Database]
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname]...
GO
```